# Akka difference between actorSelection and resolveActorRef

Tags: java, akka, actor-model

i m using two different ways for get the same result but at one i need to specify a call back time why ?
Them dose the same things ?

```
    ActorRef resolveActorRef = getContext().getSystem()
                .provider() .resolveActorRef(ActorPath.fromString("akka://RootRemoteActors/user/$a/remote.actors.AA"));
```

The code above retrive an actor Ref without waiting any time 
Why if i do not get the proveider i have to specify a time duration?

```
      ActorSelection actorSelection = getContext().getSystem()
            .actorSelection( ActorPath.fromString("akka://RootRemoteActors/user/$a/remote.actors.AA"));



       ActorRef ois = actorSelection.resolveOne( new Timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS  ))
                .value().get().get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious difference is probably that an `ActorSelection` can represent multiple `ActorRef`s if you use wildcards in the actor path. So if you just call `.tell` on your `actorSelection` instead of `resolveOne` you deliver the message to all matching actors.

I never used `resolveActorRef` but from what I can see from the sources ([ActorRefProvider](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorRefProvider.scala#L707) and [ActorSelection](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSelection.scala#L65)) `ActorRefProvider` uses `getChild` on the `rootGuardian` to find that `Actor` you are looking for and therefore traverses from the top of your actor tree down until he finds it eventually (or not).

`ActorSelection` tries to send an `Identify` message using the ask-pattern (therefore the timeout) to the selection and if it receives a response it will provide the `ActorRef` from which it got the response.

`resolveActorRef` seems to be used if you write your own serializer: [Akka Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/serialization.html#serializing-actorrefs), so if you just want to resolve an actor, I would go with the `ActorSelection` (which you btw. don't have to resolve in order to send a message to it).